# Activity or Fragment for a SearchView?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I´m doing my final degree project and I have chose to develop and Android app using Firebase Firestore, the idea it´s cool because I´m learning how to program on Android, but on Java.

So, I have develop the SplashScreen, Login form, SignIn form and able to connect succesfully with Firebase but right now I´m having a problem about thinking the main activity, which is the one that the user will see the most.

[Main View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGFPd.png)

-The idea is to set a box for search, but once the user click on it, should appear the view on the right. The main question is if it should be a Fragment or a new Activity?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's good to use **DialogFragment**.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment

Comment: Thanks sir, didn´t know about it existence but seems pretty useful for what I´m looking for.

Comment: See the link in my answer, if my answer is correct please check it

Comment: Hi, it is, sorry but I didn't know how to check it... By the way, could I ask you if which cases are better activities or fragments? Thank you

Comment: Hi, activities and fragments have advantages and disadvantages in compare with each other